# How to force Firefox error console?

Tags: firefox

How to force Firefox to open error console every time a JavaScript error occurs?

I often overlook some bugs while developing because of that, but let's say I don't want to have Firebug enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can always open your firefox with the jsconsole enabled by adding

`-jsconsole`

to the command line.

It's not exactly a "when error" occur, but can save some mouse clicks in the long run